# How is screen resolution related to cookie harvesting?

Tags: javascript, c#, cookies

Basically I am trying to harvest _abck cookies from websites such as Nike and Footlocker with Akamai automation tool protection and use for later. I find that under different screen resolutions, I might and might not get a valid cookie.

Here is what I have found out for now:

1. 1080P, 100% scaling: Yes
2. 1080P, 125% scaling: Yes
3. 2K, 100%：Yes
4. 4K, 100%: No

Above are all under same machine  (A AWS cloud server), visited from same device, with .Net Framework 4.8 installed.

May I know how does resolution matter in obtaining cookies because technically it should not have any impact?